# Jquery Добавить проверку условие

Tags: html, css, jquery

Сейчас если сделать клик вне квадратов, то они удаляются. Нужно добавить условие, чтоб квадрат при наличии класса special не закрывался и при этом если разрешение меньше 900px. Только при выполнении этих 2 условий, квадрат special не должен закрываться

```js
$(document).click(function (event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest(".item-container").length) return;
  $(".item-container").hide();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.item-container.special {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item-container"></div>
  <div class="item-container special"></div>
  <div class="item-container"></div>
  <div class="item-container special"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а в чем именно сложность то? т.е. вам надо 1) у элемента получить список классов, 2) узнать, есть ли в них нужный вам класс `special` 3) определить размер окна 4) сделать выводы

Comment: напишите в чем ваша проблема. что конкретно вы не знаете как сделать? ... определить размер окна, или как получить класс?...